# Issue regarding duplicate android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am facing issue while building the apk..

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper$Callback.class

The Dependencies i have added is :

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/utilities.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:7.4.01'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this dependency `compile files('libs/gcm.jar')`

You already have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'`

**EDIT**

Internally some library depends on `support-v4` with x- version so gradle link that with your project. Check which artifact having `support-v4` and manually exclude `support-v4` from that artifact like this.

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

It's better to use group name with artifact and version to compile instead of jars if artifact is available in any repository.

Comment: I Removed it but still the error is for "android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper$Callback.class"

Comment: Clean your project and refresh dependency

Comment: You have to remove the jar file, since you are using compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes you're right, By mistake I've not seen that.

Comment: Cleaned But still its showing the same . I excluded v4 support from everywhere. Still i don't understand where it is duplicate.